# Nuxt Error: Request failed with status code 503

Tags: node.js, vue.js, iis, nuxt.js, iisnode

We have a nuxt project that connects to .net core web services. This project will be re-signed, we got an error like it will revive its basepath. getting error in checking web api url also.

The previously working path did not contain the "hub" part and the project was running smoothly. Now we added "hub" and the project stopped working.

Can you help me please?

```
    {
    “error”: {
           “name”: “getContentByUrl”,
           “url”: “https://www.[site_name].com/hub/web/api/Commons/GetContentByUrl?url=/”,
    “error”: {
      “message”: “Request failed with status code 503",
      “name”: “Error”,
      “stack”: “Error: Request failed with status code 503\n at createError (C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\[site_name]HubFrontend\\node_modules\\axios\\lib\\core\\createError.js:16:15)\n at settle (C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\[site_name]HubFrontend\\node_modules\\axios\\lib\\core\\settle.js:17:12)\n at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\[site_name]HubFrontend\\node_modules\\axios\\lib\\adapters\\http.js:260:11)\n at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)\n at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)\n at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)“,
      “config”: {
        “url”: “https://www.[site_name].com/hub/web/api/Commons/GetContentByUrl?url=/”,
        “method”: “get”,
        “headers”: {
          “Accept”: “text/plain, */*“,
          “cache-control”: “max-age=0",
          “connection”: “keep-alive”,
          “accept-encoding”: “gzip, deflate”,
          “accept-language”: “en-US,en;q=0.9,tr;q=0.8",
          “cookie”: “_ga=GA1.2.286333093.1622573542; _hjid=13111acd-e384-41a3-8060-b99ab23ce7f9; cf_clearance=36a555f6fec78071dce12d7309d65a3c279a9ada-1628010752-0-150; _gid=GA1.2.1433373231.1628010754; i18n_redirected=tr; prb_session=eyJpdiI6IkUzWm9UNTU4MmtCQU9MYlM4bUxsbUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiakNjNm9wQTVTd1cxSG5SMHNZMUViSkpXMHlHaVpFNHptQm13Q3pPRkx4VU90b1JpbE9KWlhSSElpQUowOHRma0F3UG1CZWRQWnpoTnpOK1ovbis4TE5md1B1alI5ajQ3NGRQOUp4Um1VTURrSDNmR2gvaGNCTDdWUEZyTGJacGUiLCJtYWMiOiI1MDI3MGQ3MjFhZjRmZTQ0ZDRiOWIyYWU3YjRiZjBmN2QwM2U0MWE1YWQ1NGM1ODJmOGQ3ZTBkYTk3NjI0MjI2In0%3D; __cf_bm=9f0e439cd8992d380d6573b473ef4bfd1cfc2dd3-1628063454-1800-AWljGoT/MVhBAZzSPSDL384pPswBk2K5LnHP8oUv1WkPTkeD/x/FWdT+jVPdtV6hAt9O6ScIxn2OnfeOvfqDcDA=“,
          “user-agent”: “Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36",
          “x-forwarded-for”: “212.125.31.00, 162.158.94.170",
          “x-amzn-trace-id”: “Root=1-610a4aeb-0d3c01c765927dd1097b245e”,
          “cf-ipcountry”: “TR”,
          “cf-visitor”: “{\“scheme\“:\“https\“}”,
          “sec-ch-ua”: “\”Chromium\“;v=\“92\“, \” Not A;Brand\“;v=\“99\“, \“Google Chrome\“;v=\“92\“”,
          “sec-ch-ua-mobile”: “?0”,
          “upgrade-insecure-requests”: “1”,
          “sec-fetch-site”: “same-origin”,
          “sec-fetch-mode”: “navigate”,
          “sec-fetch-user”: “?1”,
          “sec-fetch-dest”: “document”,
          “x-serve-from”: “hub-frontend”,
          “cdn-loop”: “cloudflare”,
          “x-original-url”: “/hub/“,
          “Accept-Language”: “tr-TR”
        },
        “baseURL”: “”,
        “transformRequest”: [
          {

          }
        ],
        “transformResponse”: [
          {

          }
        ],
        “timeout”: 0,
        “adapter”: {

        },
        “xsrfCookieName”: “XSRF-TOKEN”,
        “xsrfHeaderName”: “X-XSRF-TOKEN”,
        “maxContentLength”: -1,
        “maxBodyLength”: -1,
        “validateStatus”: {

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://http.cat/503 Looks like there is no service at `/hub`?

Comment: “https://www.[site_name].com/hub/web/api/Commons/GetContentByUrl?url=/” adress is working.

Comment: What is the call that you're doing here? Also, does it work in like Postman?

Comment: yes, it works in postman. This call is, get request. It json data return

Comment: The 503 error may be related to application pool, you refer to this [document](https://bobcares.com/blog/iis-http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable/) and have a try with the solution in the document.